# VBS Script read protection

Tags: vbscript, permissions

I have a VBS script with some login information that should be kept hidden from the average user, so the script should not be readable. The script should be executeable for the average user. I have tried the "Execute only" permissions and the "read only" permission. Setting them to true and false. I've read on the internet later that this isn't possible, because it needs to read the code to run it. So I want to know, is there any way I can convert the VBS file without needing to recode it, into something that can be executeable but not readable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. VBS (Visual Basic Script) is just exactly that - a scripting language - and it's read and interpreted by cscript/wscript as text. If you want something that is compiled so the source isn't visible, use a language that has a compiler.

Comment: Is it possible to make it into an exe or VBE, and make it harder to read?

Comment: @Chutney Not really. There are some programs that does it, but what they do is just extract the source script to temporary folder and then execute from there.

Comment: Don't ever think that you are save using those kind of tools when you want to hide your passwords and your sensitive datas,  Here is an example to catch any files in your temporary folder [Bat2Exe_Files_Catcher.bat](https://pastebin.com/LGzywPCn)  to catch any files with those extensions ("*.bat" "*.vbs" "*.cmd" "*.exe") located on the temporary folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample batch file for encoding files in Base 64 with **Certutil utility**.

**How to use it ?**

Just save this code on your notepad as: ***Certutil_B64_Encoding_Files.bat*** and drag and drop any file over it to be encoded

```bat
@echo off
Title Encoding files with CERTUTIL utility by Hackoo 2017
color 0A & Mode 83,3
If "%~1"=="" ( 
    color 0C & Mode 80,3
    echo(
    echo       You must drag and drop a file over this batch script to be encoded !
    Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & exit /b
)
@for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)
set "TempFile=%Temp%\Temp_b64
set "OutputFile=%~nx1_encoded%~x0"
If exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%" >nul 2>&1
echo(
echo         Please wait a while ... Encoding "%~nx1" is in progress ...
certutil.exe -f -encode "%~1" "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo CERTUTIL -f -decode "%%~f0" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1" ^>nul 2^>^&1 
    echo Start "%~n1" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1"
    echo Exit
)> "%OutputFile%"
copy "%OutputFile%" /b + "%TempFile%" /b >nul 2>&1
If exist "%TempFile%" Del "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
```

**Encoded HTA Example: CommandLine.hta_encoded.bat**

[image]

This is a result of an encoded output of a HTA file, So, you should copy and paste this code as ***[CommandLine.hta_encoded.bat](https://pastebin.com/raw/v2kyWycq)*** and execute it by double click

**Encoded VBS Example : DJBuzzRadio.vbs_encoded.bat**

```bat
@echo off 
CERTUTIL -f -decode "%~f0" "%Temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs" >nul 2>&1 
Start "DJBuzzRadio" "%Temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs"
Exit
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
UGxheSAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jaG9jcmFkaW9zLmNoL2RqYnV6enJhZGlvX3dpbmRv 
d3MubXAzLmFzeCINClN1YiBQbGF5KFVSTCkNCiAgIERpbSBTb3VuZA0KICAgU2V0 
IFNvdW5kID0gQ3JlYXRlT2JqZWN0KCJXTVBsYXllci5PQ1giKQ0KICAgU291bmQu 
VVJMID0gVVJMDQogICBTb3VuZC5zZXR0aW5ncy52b2x1bWUgPSAxMDANCiAgIFNv 
dW5kLkNvbnRyb2xzLnBsYXkNCiAgIGRvIHdoaWxlIFNvdW5kLmN1cnJlbnRtZWRp 
YS5kdXJhdGlvbiA9IDANCiAgICAgICB3c2NyaXB0LnNsZWVwIDEwMA0KICAgbG9v 
cA0KICAgd3NjcmlwdC5zbGVlcCAoaW50KFNvdW5kLmN1cnJlbnRtZWRpYS5kdXJh 
dGlvbikrMSkqMTAwMA0KRW5kIFN1Yg0K 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```